# Blending several images together

Tags: software, post-processing, photo-editing, software-recommendation

I have several similar images (17 at the moment), which I would like to blend/overlap so that I can see a combination of all the air bubbles in total.

I've tried to place the images on top of each other while lowering the opacity in Photoshop, but this didn't work very well. Is there any tool, method or software which would allow me to achieve this?

For reference, a couple of my example images: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeiNu.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCs0d.jpg).

Comment: Don't change the opacity but change the blend mode.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-77eba.html According to this screen might give good results. I tried it in Gimp and Screen is okay.

Comment: Or "lighten". This is suggested here: http://blog.tinyenormous.com/2009/10/04/star-trail-stacking-in-photoshop/

Comment: Do you want all of the air bubbles from the different images to be recognizable (that is, increase the sheer number of bubbles), or do you want them to be smoothed out into one blended image (as if you had a single longer exposure)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a program use as COmbineZ; normally used for improving the depth of field of a macro shot it should be able to layer your images together well.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CombineZ for links to the freeware software.

IF that fails, which might depends on the algorithm (it may try and align the images rather than just stacking) then the star trail action from http://www.schursastrophotography.com/software/photoshop/startrails.html it will simply open all the files in a folder and layer them for you.

On reflection, I'd try the star trail action first !

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could try hdrinstant. You would need Lightroom though and it's not its primary function

Comment: Could you give a little more detail? What is this tool, and why/how would it work for this use case?

Comment: I am about to suggest this on an HDR thread that just came up! I will get back to you asap :)

Comment: It's software for hdr images with movement but it may work for you as it automatically aligns images - as you want to count the bubbles in your final image, it might be able to do this.